# cairo split image

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

In my gtk+ application i need to split image with high resolution. How can i make it with cairo? Where can i find example?

Thank you

Comment: Also what do you mean by high resolution?  What is it about high resolution that causes you problems?  An example would be nice

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick should serve your purposes better. It is much better suited to image manipulation.